# What is C:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM

Tags: windows, operating-systems

I've seen several articles on *C:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM* being either corrupt or missing but I've always been curious as to what the purpose of this file is, as well as the purpose of remainder of files under *C:\Windows\System32\config*

Can someone please help me understand what these files are beyond telling me that they are system files.

Comment: They are the Windows Registry. Specifically, SYSTEM is exactly that, the hkey_local_machine\system you see when you open `regedit`.

Comment: Time for some reading.....https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry

Answer (score 4):

`%SystemRoot%\System32\config` is the main location for [system registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) files in Windows NT.

Windows NT stores the registry in a binary file format which is meant to be loaded by the Registry Editor (`%windir%\regedit.exe`).

According to Wikipedia, the following system registry files are stored in: `%SystemRoot%\System32\config`:

- Sam (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM`)
- Security (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY`)
- Software (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`)
- System (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM`)
- Default (`HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT`)
- Userdiff (not associated with a hive, used only during upgrades)

In addition to the registry files in `%SystemRoot%\System32\config`, there are also `%USERPROFILE%\Ntuser.dat` and `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Usrclass.dat`, which are user-specific.